# How increased current carrying capacity / ampacity affects wire gauge size

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, conductors

In selecting a suitable wire size for manufacturing:

If I have a material that has the same resistivity and density as Copper, but has a higher current carrying capacity / ampacity for the same gauge (i.e. diameter and area), would I be able to use a thinner gauge wire? I am trying to understand how, all other things being equal, increased current carrying capacity would affect wire gauge size and why?

Comment: I'm going to redirect this question to the Electrical Engineering SE.

Comment: What do you mean by "suitable"? "Suitable" for what purpose?

Comment: assume coil winding for magnet wire

Answer (score 1):

It's all about heat buildup.   A superconductor will, occasionally, lose coolant and quench, and you need enough conductivity of the windings to prevent that quench event from melting, straining or otherwise damaging your device.  In non-superconducting wiring, the wire must not heat its surroundings (or itself) beyond the failure temperature, and the allowed currents for insulated house and appliance wiring reflect the thermal character of the surroundings.

One wants the time constant, L/R, for a quenching superconducting coil to be long enough that the dumped heat is spread over a large volume of the conductor, to limit the local temperature peak.  Melting would be bad, evaporation worse.

Comment: I think your answer is specific to superconductors (quenching etc). I was asking about a more general material question.

Comment: The material of the wire does not set the current-carrying capacity; it depends on the service conditions of the wire and its insulation and surroundings, in many different ways.